# Can a freestyle Jenkins job configured with only Deploy war to container plugin be parameterized + corresponding groovy syntax in jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I tried/google to get equivalent groovy snippet which would do exact activity which "Deploy war to container" does for a Freestyle job.

Whatever I found in more than a week perm-comb are concluding to use SSH-Agent (which requires a private key generation on unix system, which I cannot do).While "Deploy war to container" takes only username and password and deploys war to remote Unix server.[This username and password is unix system user.]

Leaving this request I tried to create a parameterized Jenkins freestyle job which has only a post build action.In that post build action "Deploy war to container" section should accept $warFilename , $tomcatUrl like.
But this job is not working.

[Jenkins job config image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qaxFz.png)

```
I tried below two syntax ,First one is for calling parameterized job.
2nd One is for using username_pasword to execute scp.

stage ('deploy:tomcat') {
            steps{
                build job: 'TOMCAT_DEPLOYMENT', parameters: [string(name: 'WAR_FILES', value: "app_Pipeline/build/libs/Test.war"), string(name: 'TOMCAT_PATH', value: 'http://ip:port')]
            }
        }
        stage ('deploy:tomcat') {
            steps{
               sshagent(['SSH_AGENT_cred']) {
               sh 'scp /some-path/build/libs/Test.war admin@destinationIp:/apache-tomcat-8/webapps/'
                    }
            }
}
```

1) Can we have a groovy syntax which can deploy war on remote server.(using only username and password , no private key related prerequisites ) ?

or

2) A jenkins freestyle job which can be generic enough to take war file path and tomcat details to deploy ?

Comment: do you use deploy to container plugin ?

Comment: @Shivendra Gupta : yes I have many jobs using this plugin for deployment of war on remote tomcat server successfully, These jobs have chekout-build-deploy all the steps.But I created a parameterized jenkins job with only post build section having "deploy war to container" and this suppose to be a generic job accepts $war_file and $Tomcat_URL.Somehow this generic job is not working.